# Custom Taxonomy Tag Search

Tags: plugins, theme-development, custom-taxonomy, functions, search

I have an existing WordPress search function, what I'd like to be able to do is extend the search to the tags from my custom taxonomy...how do I do that?

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
    <input type="text" value="Product Search..." name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/icosearch.png" id="searchsubmit" value="" />
</form>
```

I tried to use the "Search Everything" plugin, but that functionality doesn't seem to extend to custom taxonomies. I'm not sure if there is a different plugin or some kind of filter that would get the job done.

Thanks in advance!
Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One plugin that I've used successfully is Relevanssi: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/

Also, you could try to make your custom taxonomy into a search filter, like it's described in this post: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/search-form-with-custom-taxonomy-dropdown . I've used this on my projects and it worked wonders!

Hope this helps!